# Ajax results filtering and URL parameters

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am building a results filtering page using AJAX requests. I would like to reflect the filters in the URL. For example: for `price_from` I want to add `?price_from=VAL` to the URL.

I have a backend that is capable of rendering the page with URL parameters.

After some googling I would a Backbone.router solution which has a hash fallback for the IE that does not support HTML5 history API.

I have a problem with setting a good philosophy of routes. I have a set of filtering parameters (`price_from`, `price_to`, `color`, ...) and I would like to attach each parameter to one route.

Is that possible to chain the routes to match for example: `?price_from=0&price_to=1&color=red`? (the item order can change)

It means: call all the routes at the same time and keep the ie backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to have a query portion of the URL rather than using GET parameters to denote the search criteria. For example:

- Push state: `/search/query/price_from=0&price_to=1&color=red`
- Hash based: `#search/query/price_from=0&price_to=1&color=red`

Your backend would of course need to change a bit to be able to parse the new URL structure.